# How can I implement a scrolling label in Kivy without using Builder (or a .kv file)?

Tags: kivy

I am trying to implement a scrolling label in a Kivy program, and found this example (slightly modified) that works:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

long_text = "".join(["this is a long line "+str(n)+"\n" for n in range(1,101)])

Builder.load_string('''
<ScrollableLabel>:
    Label:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        text_size: self.width, None
        text: root.text
''')

class ScrollableLabel(ScrollView):
    text = StringProperty('')

class ScrollApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScrollableLabel(text=long_text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ScrollApp().run()
```

Partly for my own education, I am trying to convert this sample to not use Builder (and not resort to a .kv file).  I have modified the above example to:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

long_text = "".join(["this is a long line "+str(n)+"\n" for n in range(1,101)])

class ScrollableLabel(ScrollView):
    text = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScrollableLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.label = Label(size_hint_y=None, text=self.text)
        self.label.height = self.label.texture_size[1]
        self.label.text_size = (self.label.width, None)
        self.add_widget(self.label)

class ScrollApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScrollableLabel(text=long_text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ScrollApp().run()
```

To my obviously untutored eye, these programs look like they should be equivalent.  However, my (second) version doesn't work correctly (on several fronts).

So my question is two-fold: why doesn't the second version work the same as the first, and (if the answer isn't obvious from the first), how can I make it do so?

Thanks!  -David

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

long_text = "".join(["this is a long line "+str(n)+"\n" for n in range(1,101)])


class ScrollableLabel(ScrollView):
    text = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScrollableLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.label = Label(size_hint_y=None, text=self.text)
        self.add_widget(self.label)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.update, 1)

    def update(self, *args):
        self.label.text_size = (self.label.width, None)
        self.label.height = self.label.texture_size[1]


class ScrollApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScrollableLabel(text=long_text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ScrollApp().run()
```

the output now is the same as your first

Comment: Wow, nice.  Thank you for the answer!  Now I need to study and see if I can figure out why I need to schedule the update for the height and text_size.  A good learning opportunity.  :-)

Comment: As as follow-up, using "Clock.schedule_once(self.update, -1)" works as well.  The "-1" says before the next frame, while "1" waits a second before the update.  While they appear the same on the screen, the "-1" may be a more efficient choice.  THanks again,

Comment: It's better to bind the update function to self.label.width and self.label.height.
`self.label.bind(width=self.update, height=self.update)`
instead of calling it through Clock, because if text changes later, it will update this wax.